# Go to random page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, random

I'd like to program A page with a single button, when i press it, one of the pages (from a list in Javascript code) should be randomly opened. How do I do it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's see. There's

- `Math.random()`, which will give you a random number between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive)
- `window.location`, a property to which you can assign a URL to take the browser to a new page
- Arrays, which can contain strings, which can be URLs

Put them together, and you have the ability to pick a URL at random (from the array, using `Math.random`) and tell the browser to go there.

Comment: To build on T.J.'s answer, there is one potentially tricky bit remaining: converting a random decimal (from `Math.random()`) to a random index. You can get that with `min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1))`